# How can I access Stack Overflow in a safe way?

Tags: discussion, support

Stack Overflow doesn't support https.

How can I access Stack Overflow with the communication encrypted?

Potentially everyone is reading and logging all network communication.

Is VNC a good solution? Is there an easier way?

Comment: How would VNC fit in there?

Comment: access a desktop/server via enrypted vnc, that way my company cannot read the suff I post

Comment: Easy: Stop accessing SO from work if your company is not supposed to know that you're using SO. They can read the stuff anyway, Internet being public and so...

Comment: Using HTTPS alone wouldn't be "safe" from the prying eyes of an IT department, as the logs will still contain all your accessed URLs.

Comment: thanks for all the answers. I from europe. we are allowed to use stackoverflow from work and all is fine. it's just a precaucion because the employer is limited allowed to log internet use and I just want to be sure. thanks again!!

Comment: Surely if the employer does monitor and allow some internet use then using some encryption will make them suspicious and any good security should then ask you what you are doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use a SOCKS proxy when I want to get around an over zealous corporate nanny.

From my desktop (I use Debian):

```
ssh -CND 8185 user@myvps.someotherplace.com
```

And then I configure my browser to use the local SOCKS proxy. It all goes in/out over SSH (at least until the point where it is posted on a .. you know .. public site).

Unless your employer is able to identify your account on SO, you'd be fine. You can also use any one of the several VPN services, but I found that (at least for me), many net nannies are more adamant about rejecting unapproved VPN traffic than they are SSH.

Comment: PuTTy is a free-as-in-beer SSH client which can do the same thing for you on Windows.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do the same thing with Putty, too - I just never investigated it. Feel free to make an edit indicating how that's done.

Comment: @Piskvor'sSemifiniteMonkeys: I thought [it would be free-as-in-dom](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/licence.html)?

Comment: @Padded Cell: Aha, even better; good point. I have to admit I haven't studied the license model for PuTTy; knowing that it's *at least* free-to-use was sufficient for me, back when I started using it.

Comment: Oh, and apparently I linked the wrong post previously. How to tunnel HTTP through SSH, using PuTTY: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-tunnel-traffic-with-ssh/

Answer (score 6):

Against what exactly do you want to protect yourself? Most of the information on SO is publicly available, encrypting it in transfer to you would not prevent anyone from seeing it.

There is some non-public information on SO, but as long as you're not a moderator it is really not all that much. There's your flag history, voting history and possibly moderator messages, but that's pretty much it.

If you just want to prevent anyone watching your traffic from seeing which pages you access, you might want to use something to anonymize your traffic like [TOR](https://www.torproject.org/) (it won't protect the content of your traffic though).

Answer (score 1):

Where are you accessing SE sites from?

i) From work: You could set up VNC from your work computer to your home computer, and use that to connect to SE sites.  You are responsible for following (or not) your employer's computer use policies.

ii) From public WIFI networks: Don't use open wifi.  Don't use WEP.  WPA protects your communications so other people on the same WPA can't sniff your traffic.

But, as others have said, I'm not sure *why* you'd want this?

Comment: Just as a precaution, we are allow to use SO and there is currently no network monitoring. But I would like to be anonym as a precaution. also its central europe so the laws are in this regard are very fine, because company is not allowed to monitor internet use, but only in a limited way they can do it.